# Spring @PreAuthorize. Null context object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

Я хочу переделать данное выражение

```
User user = getAuthUser(authentication, userService);
        if (user.getUsername()
                .equals(testService.findTest(id)
                        .getUser().getUsername()))
```

Используя @PreAuthorize аннотацию

```
@PreAuthorize("#testService.findTest(#id).user.username.equals(#userController.getAuthUser(authentication,#userService).username)")
```

После вызова метода я получаю

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: Method call: Attempted to call method findTest(java.lang.Integer) on null context object
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить. И вообще можно ли этого добиться

Полный код метода и используемых переменных

```
 @Autowired
        private TestService testService;

@Autowired
    public UserService userService;
    
    @PutMapping(path = "/update/{id}", consumes={"application/json"})
        @ResponseBody
        @PreAuthorize("#testService.findTest(#id).user.username.equals(#userController.getAuthUser(authentication,#userService).username)")
        public void changeTest(@PathVariable Integer id, @Valid @RequestBody Test test,
                               Authentication authentication, UserService userService) throws ResponseStatusException {
            User user = getAuthUser(authentication, userService);
            if (user.getUsername()
                    .equals(testService.findTest(id)
                            .getUser().getUsername())) {
    
                for (int i = 0; i < test.getQuizzes().size(); i++) {
                    Quiz oldQuiz = testService.findTest(id).getQuizzes().get(i);
                    Quiz quiz = test.getQuizzes().get(i);
                    quizService.updateQuiz(oldQuiz.getId(), quiz.getTitle(), quiz.getText(), (ArrayList<String>) quiz.getOptions(), (ArrayList<Integer>) quiz.getAnswer());
                }
    
            } else {
                throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
            }
    
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы избежать ошибки необходимо использовать аннотацию так:

```
@PreAuthorize(value = "@testService.findTest(#id).user.username.equals(@userController.getAuthUser(authentication,@userService).username)")
```